# Хотел сделать что-то типа кликера

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var c = 0;

function Click() {
  с++;
}

//while (true) {
//  закомментировал, потому, что это бесконечный цикл...
//document.getElementById('click').innerHTML = c;
//}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Клик" onclick="Click()" />
<div id="click"></div>
```

Что не так?

Comment: А вы попробуйте выполнить код.

Comment: @0xdb какой злой дядя)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский где?  я? я не злой, я справедливый

Answer (score 2):

как минимум

```
while (true) {
```

запускает бесконечный цикл, который вешает страницу...

а `c` - похоже местами была **русская**. В связи с чем стоит понять, что переменные должны иметь осмысленные имена, а не как после обфускации

```js
var count = 0;

function Click() {  
  document.getElementById('click').innerHTML = count++;
}

Click();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Кликер</title>
  <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" value="Клик" onclick="Click()" />
  <div id="click"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Правда, имейте в виду, что значения на странице и в `count` при таком раскладе будут различаться на единицу.

Comment: @D-side угу. хотел написать через `++count`, но подумал, что для автора будет это всё не критично